# Vaadin14: How to get base directory?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

In Vaadin8 I could get the path for the base directory with

```
    VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

How can I do this in Vaadin14?

Comment: What is the problem you're solving with the help of the base directory path?

Comment: I want to store a file that gets created if a user clicks the download data button. In the end I want to use your file-download-wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the vaadin forum is a question with a [answer](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17283562/how-to-get-the-absolute-path-in-vaadin-10) that describes how to do this with Vaadin 10. But I believe this should also work for Vaadin 14.
You basically have to write a small helper class. You can find an example on the forum.